# How to create a label with drag and drop function and with the clicked signal function QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm developing a program that contains a MainWindow and a Widget called Diagrama from `QWidget`, which is the central widget of my mainwindow.

In this diagrama widget I have the ability to create a label in a the position that I clicked on the screen and the ability to drag an drop those same labels.

But now, I want to add an ability to get a clicked signal of the label every time that I click it.

I know that to enable the clicked signal function of a label, I have to create a class of a custom label, but when I do this and I replace the class `QLabel` to the customLabel class in the code, the drag and drop function stop working.

```cpp
void Diagrama::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{....}

void Diagrama::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{....}

void Diagrama::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{....}

void Diagrama::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{....}
```

I put this for just you guys know that I have the function to the whole process

And now I don't know what to do.
I though that there is a conflict of the function `mousePressEvent` of my `customLabel` class and the same function in my `Diagrama` class.

How can I solve it?

---

```cpp
void Diagrama::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void Diagrama::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    if (event->mimeData()->hasFormat("application/x-dnditemdata")) {
        QByteArray itemData = event->mimeData()->data("application/x-dnditemdata");
        QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        QPixmap pixmap;
        QPoint offset;
        dataStream >> pixmap >> offset;

        QLabel *newIcon = new QLabel(this);
        newIcon->setPixmap(pixmap);
        newIcon->move(event->pos() - offset);
        newIcon->show();
        newIcon->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

        if (event->source() == this) {
            event->setDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
            event->accept();
        } else {
            event->acceptProposedAction();
        }
    } else {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void Diagrama::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawImage(0,0,*mImage);
    e->accept();
}

void Diagrama::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{


    if(modo=="trafo")
    {
        if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton){
            QLabel *child = static_cast<QLabel*>(childAt(event->pos()));
            if (!child)
                return;

            QPixmap pixmap = *child->pixmap();

            QByteArray itemData;
            QDataStream dataStream(&itemData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
            dataStream << pixmap << QPoint(event->pos() - child->pos());

            QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
            mimeData->setData("application/x-dnditemdata", itemData);

            QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
            drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
            drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
            drag->setHotSpot(event->pos() - child->pos());

            QPixmap tempPixmap = pixmap;
            QPainter painter;
            painter.begin(&tempPixmap);
            painter.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), QColor(127, 127, 127, 127));
            painter.end();

            child->setPixmap(tempPixmap);

            if (drag->exec(Qt::CopyAction | Qt::MoveAction, Qt::CopyAction) == Qt::MoveAction) {
                child->close();
            } else {
                child->show();
                child->setPixmap(pixmap);
            }
        }
        else if(event->button()==Qt::RightButton)
        {

            QLabel *child = new QLabel(this);
            child->setPixmap(QPixmap(url_trafo));
            child->move(event->x(),event->y());
            child->show();

        }

    }
    else if(modo=="linha")
    {
        if(event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
            p_ini=event->pos();
             drawing=true;
            event->accept();}

        else {
            event->ignore();
            drawing=false;
        }
    }

}
```

That is the responsible for the events of drag and drop and the event of appearing a label every time I click on the screen

I tried to create a customLabel class to emit a clicked signal every time I click in the label, but disable the drag and drop event

Comment: You have to provide your code, not just your method signatures.

Comment: you want all of it?

Comment: The minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A click has to be registered on mouse release, not mouse press. A mouse press can evolve into different things, depending on what the user does next. Mouse press plus move or mouse press plus a long delay evolves into a drag operation.

So you need to override both `mousePressEvent()` as well as `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

In your `mousePressEvent()` you need to save the time the press happened as well as the position. You then call `QLabel::mousePressEvent()` and pass it the event, so that QLabel can still detect drag operations.

In your `mouseReleaseEvent()` you need to compare the current time to the time of the press. If the difference is larger than [QApplication::startDragTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#startDragTime-prop), or the position of the mouse release compared to the mouse press position is further away than [QApplication::startDragDistance](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#startDragDistance-prop), or the position is outside the label, then you don't treat the mouse release as a click. Finally, forward the event to the overriden `QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent()` so that the base class knows the mouse press event ended.

Here's an example `ClickableQLabel` implementation:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPoint>

class ClickableQLabel: public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClickableQLabel(QWidget* parent = nullptr)
        : QLabel(parent)
    {}

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override
    {
        QLabel::mousePressEvent(e);
        if (e->button() != Qt::LeftButton) {
            rerurn;
        }
        mouse_press_time_.start();
        mouse_press_pos_ = e->pos();
        e->accept();
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override
    {
        QLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
        if (!rect().contains(e->pos(), true)
            || e->button() != Qt::LeftButton
            || !mouse_press_time_.isValid()
            || mouse_press_pos_.isNull()
            || mouse_press_time_.hasExpired(QApplication::startDragTime())
            || (e->pos() - mouse_press_pos_).manhattanLength() >= QApplication::startDragDistance())
        {
            // Not a click.
            return;
        }
        e->accept();
        mouse_press_time_.invalidate();
        mouse_press_pos_ = QPoint();
        emit clicked();
    }

private:
    QElapsedTimer mouse_press_time_;
    QPoint mouse_press_pos_;
};
```

If you now want something to happen when the label is clicked, connect the `clicked()` signal.